# output in iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I have added the rule to `iptables` file, however the command does not show it.

```
$ sudo less /etc/sysconfig/iptables   
Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Oct 24 13:28:48 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [759586734:591152083716]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [753755282:560671783214]
-A INPUT -s 93.114.45.59/32 -j DROP


$ sudo iptables -L   
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

did you do a `service iptables restart` after adding it to the file? That file is just for the persistent configuration. If you want to make it active you have to restart the service.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the `-v` option of `iptables`:

```
iptables -L -v
```